# Macro to write certain cells font size in another cell range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of values in Excel - numbers in many rows.

I need Excel VBA code that writes the font sizes of these values in other empty rows in the same sheet. Below is VBA code that can do it for one row and write the font size in another row.

I need help with achieving the same result for multiple rows.

```
'executes when the user presses the Run button
Private Sub btnRun_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    'loops through the cells in row 1
    For i = 1 To 8
        'gets the font size
        Cells(3, i) = Range(Cells(1, i), _
        Cells(1, i)).Font.Size
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `I need help with achieving the same result for multiple rows.` What help do you need? What did you try to make it work and where are you stuck?

Comment: I need a code when the no. of row with data have font size change , to have the new font sizes values to be written in another rows . actually the code provided in the original post works fine but for only one row of data, i need dynamic one to loop through set of data and to write result in another rows .. hope this is clear enough

Comment: I got you the first time. My question is what did you try to make it work and where are you stuck?

Comment: http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/03/28/excel-vba-font-size/

Comment: please see last example in this link  , that where I got code in the 1st place '' am not developer '' - the case that I got excel sheet with number of rows and columns say 10  by 10 I need when this set of data font size change to have the value of the font sizes to be written in another range like 10 by 10 each row corresponding to another row. we can communicate through email if this will be better .. aimo.haggag@gmail.com

Comment: thank you so much for your time really appreciate it

Comment: @AmrHaggag made an update, I still wonder though why you would want to have this information specifically like this.

Answer (score 0):

You declare another `Integer`  variable and run it in an outer `For to` loop.

code:

```
'executes when the user presses the Run button
Private Sub btnRun_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    'loops through the cells in row 1

    for k = 1 to 8
        For i = 1 To 8
            'gets the font size
            Cells(3, i) = Range(Cells(k, i), _
            Cells(k, i)).Font.Size
       Next i
    next k
End Sub
```

**Update:**

To simply grab a `Range` and capture the `Font.Size` and `Paste` it into another `Range` you can do the following:

```
Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A25:H46") = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:H22").Font.Size
```

Where `.Range("A25:H46")` can be whichever `Range` you want to put the `Font.Size` data in and `.Range("A1:H22")` the `Range` you retrieve it from.

Comment: but we I need a code when the no. of rows with data have font size change , to have the new font sizes values to be written in another rows . actually the code provided in the original post works fine but for only one row of data, i need dynamic one to loop through set of data and to write result in another rows .. hope this is clear enough

Comment: What is the exact range you want to use, and where do you need the Font data? Example: `Row 1 data`   `Row 2 Font Data`   `Row 3 Data`   `Row 4 Font Data`

Comment: Hi , I did that and run gave me error 9 ' subscript out of range ' - the following is code as u mention      Sub Font_Size()

Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A25:H46") = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:H22").Font.Size

End Sub      ...... any clue what is wrong here

Comment: @AmrHaggag do you have a `Worksheet` named `Sheet 1`? otherwise above code won't work

Comment: Hello,  The sheet named with space , removed it and worked without giving error - but it didn't made what I need , what I did was a made range of row from A1:H22 with text in different font sizes and other range from A25:H46 to have the macro result , sure made new macro with the code u provided - then run it , the result was no error but i did not made any thing the range A25:H46 should be filled with font sizes , but it appeared with no data at all, as nothing run , all macros security are enabled !  - then what :)

Comment: @AmrHaggag and there is data in the range from A1:H22? I tested the code before posting and it places the font data in the given range.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think what you want is size of the font. I feel what you would like to have is that rows below the one you have selected should have the same font size formatting. I am submitting another program choice. You can change the font size as per your choice and can change number of rows as per your requirements. Please note that font formatting remains valid if you do manual entry or from pasting data on text editor like Note Pad or Note Tab Light and then repasting on the worksheet. If you copy paste data from another excel worksheet, your formatting may not remain valid. If you think this meets your requirement, you can attach this macro to a Command Button.

Try This :

```
  Sub FontSize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim fnt As Integer
    Dim rcnt As Long
    fnt = 16 ' Choose any Font size as you like
    rcnt = 100 'Choose number of rows to format
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
      With ws
     .Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(rcnt, 8)).Font.Size = fnt
      End With
End Sub
```

PS: Reference to your comments today Font size is visible in the ribbon as shown in the picture below.

```
[![excel ribbon][1]][1]
```

Hence logic of writing in a range is not clear. Since these cells are to be ultimately filled with data. There has to some goal with clearly stated purpose for which we have to work.

Comment: The OP asks specifically for writing the Font size to a cell. Why would you state that its not what the OP wants but OP wants something completely else?

Comment: That didn't work for me - yes this is what I need , it may seems odd , but we I need a code when the no. of rows with data have font size change , to have the new font sizes values to be written in another rows . actually the code provided in the original post works fine but for only one row of data, i need dynamic one to loop through set of data and to write result in another rows .. hope this is clear enough